# Defining rules and condition in javascript = Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

My requirement is,
The user is given the option to define rules 
for eg:

```
IF f1 is grt than f2 do this
```

or

```
IF f1 > f2 and f2 < f3 ...
```

so he may use operators or text (say `and` or `&&`)

Now we need to convert this text in a textbox to specific rules or condition. There are lots of condition (all operators `&&`, `||`, `!`, `=` etc etc...) provided it should be done in client side browser. So javascript is a way to do. I dont have enough time to write a library or a parser. However I read somewhere rhino has this ability but i have no idea how to use it.

Thanks in Advance for any hints.

Comment: Just use Rhino as the engine through Java Scripting API and evaluate Javascript scripts (with standard syntax) using eval() call http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_(JavaScript_engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to translate rules written in a custom language to javascript?

In this case, Rhino will not solve your problem: Rhino is a javascript interpreter written in Java. It would allow you to evaluate the rules if they were written in javascript.

Comment: So what i am supposed to do ??

Comment: You can either write your own translator, or have the user express the rules in javascript, or a subset of javascript. In the latter case, you could use Rhino to check the syntax of the rules.